# Physical address calculation assembly IAPX8088

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Given that: CS=0x5645, DS=0x1000, ES=0x6783, SS=0x0FFF, BX=0x4567, SI=0x1000, DI=0x2000, BP=0x4500
Write the physical address of the memory locations read or written by the following instructions if  ax=0.

```
mov ax,[si]        
mov ax,[bp]        
mov ax,cs:[bp+20]
mov ax,[bx+si+10]  
mov ss:[bx+di],ax  
mov es:[bp+si+0x200],20
```

What is the formula for calculation address this way and how to deal with segment registers in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To calculate the physical address do the following:

- All the components between the square brackets must be added together using 64KB wraparound, so sum is in [0,65535].
- The segment register's value must first be multiplied by 16 and then added to the result using 1MB wraparound, so sum is in [0,1048575]. Take care to use the correct segment register!

Example:

```
mov ax,es:[bx+si+123]
```

Physical address is **(((bx+si+123) and 0x0000'FFFF)+es*16) and 0x000F'FFFF**

Comment: Like in the first one mov ax, [si] the address will be value of si?

Comment: No. You need to add DS*16 to the value of SI. Using current numbers you get 0x1000 * 16 + 0x1000 giving 0x11000

Comment: All memory accesses use a segment register, if none are specified a default is used. For the `[si]` that's the `ds` segment. If you use `bp`, then the default is `ss` segment, otherwise it's `ds`.